Finding All Irreducible Polynomials of Degree 5 Over $\mathbb{F}_8$
I'm trying to factorize various polynomials (with their highest degree being 6) over the field of $\mathbb{F}_8$ generated by the primitive polynomial $x^3 + x + 1$ in order to do matrix inversion with the matrix having elements that are polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_8$. I understand that to do this, you must first find the minimal polynomials of degree 5 by using cyclotomic cosets of $8$ modulo $8^5-1$. That is, for example, if we take the cyclotomic coset $\{1, 8, 64, 512, 4096\}$, and use the primitive element $\theta$ of $\mathbb{F}_{8^5}$, then one monic irreducible polynomial of degree 5 with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_8$ would be $(x - \theta)(x - \theta^8)(x - \theta^{64})(x - \theta^{512})(x - \theta^{4096})$. Such polynomials will have coefficients in $\{0, 1, \theta^{4681}, \theta^{4681\times 2}, \dots, \theta^{4681\times 6}\}$, the subfield $\mathbb{F}_8 \subset \mathbb{F}_{8^5}$ generated by the primitive polynomial corresponding to primitive element $\theta$. My chief concern here is that once I've gotten all the degree 5 monic irreducible polynomials, how do I ensure that the coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_8$ of these polynomials correspond to the elements of my original field in $\mathbb{F}_8$ generated specifically by the primitive polynomial $x^3 + x + 1$. I obviously can't just use the same subfield of $\mathbb{F}_8 \subset \mathbb{F}_{8^5}$ to ensure consistency which I thought about doing at first because then when I go to find all degree 4 monic irreducible polynomials, for example, I will need to find the minimal polynomials of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{8^4}$, which will then require using a different primitive element in $\mathbb{F}_{8^4}$ to acquire the minimal polynomials as previously described.

There are $\frac{8^5-8}{5} = 6552$ such polynomials.  Are you sure that having a complete listing of all those polynomials will be useful?

Is the goal all irreducible polynomials or all primitive polynomials? If all primitive polynomials, a brute force using primitive element $\alpha = x$ would be possible, only 32768 possible sets of 5 $GF(8)$ coefficients for $x^5 ... x^0$ . All $GF(8^5)$ fields are isomorphic and can be linearly mapped from one field to another using a 5x5 matrix in $GF(8)$.

@DanielSchepler I realized this when looking at the size of the cyclotomic coset list I generated... How would you recommend going about this problem of factoring multiple polynomials of degree 6 or under? Just brute force?

@rcgldr The goal is to factorize multiple polynomials of degree 6 or under to perform matrix inversion of a 3x3 matrix. So I unfortunately will be needing all the irreducible polynomials (assuming I go about it in this manner).

Invert 3 by 3 matrix, why not Gaussian reduction, such as using an augmented 3 row by 6 column matrix, left side is matrix, right side is identity matrix, when done, left side is identity matrix, right side is inverted matrix. You mention $GF(8^4)$, but also mention degree 6, which would correspond to $GF(8^5)$?

I may be wrong, but it sounds to me that your problem is that of identifying the elements of the unique subfield isomorphic to $K=\Bbb{F}_8$ within $L=\Bbb{F}_{8^5}$.
This post is only comment-ish, because I'm not sure whether that is your chief concern or not. But this is too long to make a sensible comment.
The answer to that question depends, at least to some extent, on how you constructed those fields in the first place. You further described that you constructed $K$ as $\Bbb{F}_2(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of the polynomial $x^3+x+1$. But how did you construct $L$?
While waiting for a clarification of that question, there is another thing I need
to get off my chest. Even though $L$ has a unique subfield isomorphic to $K$, the embedding $i:K\to L$ is not unique. This is because if $\sigma:K\to K$ is one of the three automorphisms of $K$, then we can, use $i\circ \sigma$ instead of $i$. Viewed differently, the polynomial $x^3+x+1$ has three roots in $L$, and we can send $\alpha$ to any of them, and this choice gives us three distinct ways of seeing $K$ as a subset of $L$ (even though the resulting set is always the same).
A possible reason this often is a bit confusing to a student is the following (It confused me a bit the first time I ran into this problem when writing a piece of code for a purpose I have long forgotten). Anyway, the first extensions of fields a student learns about are number fields. Consider the pair $F=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$,
$E=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. Each and every one of us primarily thinks of those as subfields of $\Bbb{R}$. Consequently we prefer to identify the number $\sqrt2\in F$ with the number $\sqrt2\in E$, and think nothing of it. This is exactly because we think of both $E$ and $F$ as subsets of $\Bbb{R}$. If we had, instead, two abstract fields only known to be isomorphic to $F$ and $E$ respectively, then we would need to make a choice. Both $F$ and $E$ contain two roots of $x^2-2$. Which is which? It really is anybody's call!
On the finite field side we are always in this situation simply because there is no natural umbrella field containing a copy of each and every finite field of a given characteristic (like $\Bbb{R}$ or more commonly $\Bbb{C}$ on the number field side).
Say, if $\theta$ is a primitive element of $L$ (= a generator of the group $L^*$), then we know that $\theta^{32767/7}=\theta^{4681}$ is a root of unity of order seven. Those fall into two classes of Galois conjugates because the seventh roots of unity have either $x^3+x+1$ or the reciprocal $x^3+x^2+1$ as their minimal polynomials over the prime field. It follows that either $\theta^{4681}$ or
$\theta^{-4681}$ is a root of $x^3+x+1$, and can hence be identified with $\alpha$. Unfortunately I cannot tell you which is the case, unless you tell me how you defined $\theta$!
But in either case we arrive at the description
$$K=\{a_0+a_1\theta^{4681}+a_2\theta^{2\cdot4681}\vert a_0,a_1,a_2\in\Bbb{F}_2\}.$$
Of course, you need to reduce those high powers of $\theta$, if your program is internally using a monomial basis of powers of $\theta$ to represent elements of $L$.

If I misguessed whether this is what was bothering you, then I apologize for wasting your time, and will gladly delete. No hard feelings.
